# Flex Builder 4.10: internal build error

Tags: apache-flex

When I recompile my (previously working) Flex code using the updated Apache Flex 4.10 I get scads of "An internal build error has occurred" messages.

I have tried:

- doing a 'clean' and build
- checking various installed java versions
- building a new project with the existing code

None of these work.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall the Apache Flex 4.10 compiler but make sure to check the box marked "Remoting Support(optional)".

Yes - it says optional but if you use any remoting in your code (AMFPHP anyone?) you will need this. After reinstalling, do a clean and build.